# Applying Switch and Which to mixed-Key Association lists

Tags: dataset, conditional, slot

Given an `Association` list w/ a common `Key` but also some distinct ones:

```
data3 = {<|"commonKey" -> 1, "b" -> 3|>, <|"commonKey" -> 2, 
    "c" -> 4|>} // Dataset
```

[image]

How to implement logic similar to `Switch` and `Which` using named slots?

```
data3[All, Switch[#commonKey, 1, #b] &] // Normal
```

> `{3, Missing["Failed"]}`

```
data3[All, Switch[#commonKey, 1, #b, 2, #c] &] //Normal
```

> `{Missing["Failed"], Missing["Failed"]}`

Similarly, using `Which`:

```
data3[All, Which[#commonKey == 1, #b, #commonKey == 2, #c] &]//Normal
```

> `{Missing["Failed"], Missing["Failed"]}`

The cause is `Function::slota` Named Slot can't be filled from the association with the Key that is missing.

Is there an elegant workaround that can be mapped on existing `Association` list, as opposed to aggregating via `GroupBy[#commonKey&]`? (Reason: the actual data set that is simplified here is chronologically sorted, and grouping would not preserve the item sequence).

Comment: You really are trying to save time by abbreviating *with* w/ *w/*??

Comment: Programmable: w/, w/i, w/o ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the whole association and access it inside your function:

```
data3[All, Switch[#commonKey, 1, #["b"], _, 0] &]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this an alternative?

Comment: Not sure where the 0 comes from but did you mean to write this? `data3[All, Switch[#commonKey, 1, #["b"], 2, #["c"]] &]`? That works while `Switch[#commonKey, 1, #b, 2, #c]` .

Comment: @alancalvitti I meant to write it because I thought you might want a fallback rule if there isn't any `#b` in the association. You can just remove the part and adapt if like you want.

Comment: You may also be interested in this related q: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83414/applying-functions-to-irregularly-distributed-keys-in-association-lists