# Applying functions to irregularly distributed Keys in Association lists

Tags: dataset, associations, missing

This Q is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83199/applying-switch-and-which-to-mixed-key-association-lists), but now refer to the situation as irregularly distributed `Keys` in lists of `Associations`:

```
data4 = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>} // Dataset
```

Consider:

```
data4[All, {"a" -> Framed, "b" -> Panel}]
```

[image]

Of course this fails altogther:

```
data4[All, {"a" -> Framed, "b" -> Panel, "c" -> (Style[#, Red] &)}]
```

> `{Missing["Failed"], Missing["Failed"]}`

Is there a better way than this clearly inefficient workaround using `Lookup` and subsequent filter out based on matching `Missing`? - To avoid having to add `Missing` handlers for each function:

```
data4[All, ({"a", "b", "c"} // AssociationMap[Lookup]) /* 
    Query[{"a" -> Framed, "b" -> Panel, "c" -> (Style[#, Red] &)}]][
  All, Select[FreeQ[#, Missing["KeyAbsent", "a" | "b" | "c"]] &]] // Normal
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if its worth talking to Wolfram - it may be possible that the `MissingBehaviour` option of Query could be amended to deal with this, or that Query needs some additional intelligence to handle non uniform keys.

Comment: Already submitted to WRI tech support. Hopefully b/w `MissingBehavior`, `PartBehavior`  and `FailureAction` can rescue it.

Comment: @GordonCoale, I think `MissingBehavior` should handle this option. Will contact support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data4 = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>} // Dataset
```

You could go with the answer from [Query or MapAt ragged associations or ignoring Missing values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119603/5478)

but let's create something more general since retyping keys is ugly:

```
mapping = {"a" -> Framed, "b" -> Panel, "c" -> (Style[#, Red] &)};

data4[
 All,
 Query[  FilterRules[mapping, #] ][#] &
]
```

[image]

Comment: That works nicely - interesting that FilterRules has been around pre v10. Heres's a slightly cleaned up version: `filter[expr_][as_Association] := Query[FilterRules[expr, as]][as]`;

Comment: I belatedly noted some limitations of FilterRules in Q you linked above.

Comment: @alancalvitti since no one is using FilterRules there maybe it is better to mention it here.